# RStudio "Install and Restart" not ignoring files in .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, devtools

My .Rbuildignore specifies these files:

```
^inst/extdata$
```

This is a directory that holds some `.csv` files I use.

When I build my package with the "Install and Restart" button, these folders are included in the built package as demonstrated by:

```
> list.files(system.file(package = 'myPackage'), recursive = T, full.names = T)

...         
 [6] "C:/Users/JohnDoe/R/win-library/4.0/myPackage/extdata/df.csv"
...
```

However, if I build my package with the command `devtools::install()`, the `inst/extdata` folder is correctly ignored in the build process. This leads me to believe the discrepancy lies in the "Install and Restart" button. Is there any way to map this button to the `devtools::install()` command?

Answer (score 1):

`.Rbuildignore` is used by the `R CMD build` command.  If you install directly from a directory without building a tarball, it's not used.  This is true for base `R CMD INSTALL` as well as the `RStudio` emulations of it.

So what you should do is to put the files somewhere else that isn't handled by `R CMD INSTALL`, for example in directory `ignoreMe` instead of a directory whose name means "install me".

If you don't want to do that, then it is possible to attach arbitrary R commands to keys in RStudio, but that's a lot of work. See http://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/ if you want the details.

Comment: Is there an accepted R package convention for where to store files used in the development process but should not be installed?

Comment: I think the usual convention is to include all source in the tarball.  I don't know of a convention for files that are not intended to be installed; the only rule I know about is that the name shouldn't conflict with one of the standard names listed in Writing R Extensions section 1.1 "Package Structure".  If it's not in the tarball and not installed, nobody else will see it, so do whatever you like.